# Why do I keep getting 'Assembly must be specified for XAML files that are not part of a project' errors in a local project?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces

To start with, I would like to stress that I *do* know how to define XML Namespaces correctly in my XAML files. This repeated error is *not* caused by an mistake in my code. The problem does *not* stop my project from being built successfully, or running and the mentioned `Converter` class works perfectly.

When I build the project, the errors disappear. However, the designer show the familiar error message:

[image]

When I  click on the 'Reload the designer' link, the errors return. The worst part of this problem is that I lose all Intellisense on these views.

The error highlights these namespaces:

[image]

But you can clearly see that they have been declared correctly:

[image]

I'm sure that I have found a solution for this problem before, but after an extensive search just now, I can only find a million posts relating to this error where users have *actually* made errors. Please also note that this was a brand new WPF Application and *not* downloaded from the internet or a network drive.

Comment: are you sure when you cleanbuild your project, designer still shows this error? I usually do cleanbuild or just build again and reload the designer it works well.

Comment: I've tried *all* kind of variations of cleaning, building and rebuilding, but none of them (permanently) get rid of these errors.

Comment: yes,thats true whenever a new type/namespace is added, have to build the assembly again to which xmlns is referring. But building again reloads the designer without error. I searched for the solution sometimes back but found old "build the project" useful only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the project ON a network drive? XAML has issues with projects stored on a network drive. In corporate environments your Documents are often remapped to a network path, causing this problem for the default project folder.

Try like c:\projects\yourprojecthere instead?

[WPF Project on a network share with clr-namespace](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/568464/wpf-project-on-a-network-share-with-clr-namespace)

Comment: You know at first, I replied saying that it was a local project, but your excellent comment about corporate environments remapping the `Documents` folder reminded me that actually, this particular project *was* on a mapped network drive. Normally, I use the path 'C:\DevelopmentProjects', but as this current application that I'm working on is just a small 'helper' application, I just let Visual Studio put it wherever it wanted to... but that was on the network `Documents` folder, so thanks... great catch!

Comment: My organization established folder redirect for our "My Documents" folder causing this very issue. Thanks for the information.