# ViewModel is null when connecting to the View (in XAML)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm quite new in MVVM, so it might be a simple problem.
I have a View And ViewModel connected like this:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
        <local:MyView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

The XAML designer can't load it because of an error:
"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type".

Why is this error happending, and how can I solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: and your code is compiling?

Comment: your connection looks right so your problem should be somewhere else
your definition for `local` could be wrong ...

Comment: The code compiles and runs well. The error is in the XAML designer. "local" is also defined well, because the intellisence gives me these classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean build and reload the designer. This is the issue with the VS xaml designer.
For some more insight you can have a look on this question 
[Why do I keep getting 'Assembly must be specified for XAML files that are not part of a project' errors in a local project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659708/why-do-i-keep-getting-assembly-must-be-specified-for-xaml-files-that-are-not-pa?noredirect=1#comment27479883_18659708)

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of causes of your problem. The XML Namespace *could* be defined incorrectly, but you say that it's not that. You *could* have declared the `DataTemplate` out of scope of the `MyView` view, although that seems unlikely... I personally put these `DataTemplates` into the `App.xaml` file.

There is one more possibility... maybe the error does *not* relate to this `DataTemplate`? It says `parameter name: Type`, but there is no parameter named `Type` on the `DataTemplate`.

Comment: I'm sure the error is in the DataTemplate, because it's underlined with this wavy line of an error (The part of "{x:Type local:MyViewModel}").

Comment: If the problem goes away when you build and returns when you click on the designer and your project is on a network drive, then please see the post linked from @nit's answer.